# How to see the parameters LogisticRegression() has found where the cost is minimal?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

With sklearn's `LogisticRegression()`, how can I see the parameters it has found after `.fit()` where the cost is minimal? I use the book of Geron about scikit-learn and tensorflow and on page 137 he trains the model of petal widths. I did the following:

```
iris=datasets.load_iris()
a1=iris['data'][:,3:]
y=(iris['target']==2).astype(int)
log_reg=LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(a1,y)

log_reg.coef_
array([[2.61727777]])
log_reg.intercept_
array([-4.2209364])
```

I did the logistic regression myself with Gradient Descent or Newton-Raphson as I learned from my Coursera course and respectively from my book of Bishop. I used the Gradient Descent method like so:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris=datasets.load_iris()
a1=iris['data'][:,3:]
A1=np.c_[np.ones((150,1)),a1]
y=(iris['target']==2).astype(int).reshape(-1,1)
lmda=1

from scipy.special import expit

def logreg(w):
  z2=A1.dot(w)
  a2=expit(z2)
  delta2=a2-y
  w=w-(lmda/len(a1))*A1.T.dot(delta2)
  return w

w=np.array([[0],[0]])
for i in range(0,100000):
  w=logreg(w)

In [6219]: w
Out[6219]:
array([[-21.12563996],
       [ 12.94750716]])
```

I used Newton-Raphson like so, see Bishop page 207,

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris=datasets.load_iris()
a1=iris['data'][:,3:]
A1=np.c_[np.ones(len(a1)),a1]
y=(iris['target']==2).astype(int).reshape(-1,1)

def logreg_nr(w):
  z1=A1.dot(w)
  y=expit(z1)
  R=np.diag((y*(1-y))[:,0])
  H=A1.T.dot(R).dot(A1)
  tmp=A1.dot(w)-np.linalg.inv(R).dot(y-t)
  v=np.linalg.inv(H).dot(A1.T).dot(R).dot(tmp)
  return vw=np.array([[0],[0]])

for i in range(0,10):
  w=logreg_nr(w)

In [5149]: w
Out[5149]:
array([[-21.12563996],
       [ 12.94750716]])
```

Notice how much faster Newton-Raphson goes than Gradient Descent. But they give the same result.

How can I see which parameters `LogisticRegression()` found? And should I give `LogisticRegression` other parameters?

Comment: should we guess how you "do logistic regression yourself with Gradient Descent of Newton-Raphson as I learned from my Coursera course"???

Comment: It is the regularization term. In scikit-learn it is always there: $ \lambda $=1. When I do that too, I get the same answer as scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `LogisticRegression()` object is called `regressor`. You fit the model by doing `result = regressor.fit(X,y)`. After fitting the model, the optimization algorithm gives the Logistic Regression parameters such that cost is minimal, or in other words, the model's discrimination power is at the optimum. After fitting you'll get model parameters by using

```
result.get_params()
```

For more details see the sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

If this answer is not satisfactory, I recommend you to take a look to [Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html)

Here is a short example

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

logit = sm.Logit(y, X)

result = logit.fit()

 print(result.summary())
```

The last print statement will give you the whole table with many statistics and among them model estimated coefficients.

Comment: No. I have updated my question, so you can see where I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe the estimated coefficients in either model are scaled.

Comment: It is the regularization term. In scikit-learn it is always there: $ \lambda $=1. When I do that too, I get the same answer as scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `penalty` in param is `l2` in `LogisticRegresssion`. If we change that to `none`, we will get the same result as your implementation.

```
>>> log_reg=LogisticRegression(penalty='none',solver='newton-cg')
>>> log_reg.fit(a1,y)

>>> log_reg.coef_
[[12.94748623]]
>>> log_reg.intercept_
[-21.12560671]
```

Note: `solver` is changed because `none` is not compatible with default solver, which is `liblinear`